# How can I get the list of tables in the stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

There are lot of tables and sp in the db. I find the tables name which are used in the specific sp (stored procedure).

sp_depends `%sp_name%` not give the desire result. I am also used `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`,`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` tables.

But the result is not full fill my requirment.

Comment: Hi @user2322431 ,
  Did any of these answers solve your problem?
Could you tick one please?

Answer (score 23):

The two highest voted answers use a lot of deprecated tables that should be avoided.
Here's a much cleaner way to do it.

#### Get all the tables on which a stored procedure depends:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.name AS proc_name, t.name AS table_name
FROM sys.sql_dependencies d 
INNER JOIN sys.procedures p ON p.object_id = d.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables     t ON t.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
ORDER BY proc_name, table_name
```

*Works with MS SQL SERVER 2005+*

#### List of Changes:

- [`sysdepends`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190325.aspx) should be replaced with [`sys.sql_dependencies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402.aspx)

  - The new table uses `object_id` instead of `id`
  - The new table uses `referenced_major_id` instead of `depid`
- Using [`sysobjects`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) should be replaced with more focused system catalog views

  - As [marc_s pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229493/1366033/#comment23216013_16229560), instead use [`sys.tables`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) and [`sys.procedures`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx)
  - **Note**: This prevents having to check where `o.xtype = 'p'` (etc.)
- Also, there is really no need for a CTE which uses [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) *just* in order to make sure we only have one of each record set returned.  That's what [`DISTINCT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634943.aspx) is there for!

  - In fact, SQL is smart enough to use DISTINCT behind the scenes.
  - I submit into evidence: [**Exhibit A**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ba48/1). The following queries have the same [Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU32U.png)!

    ```sql
    -- Complex
    WITH MyPeople AS (
      SELECT id, name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY id, name) AS row
      FROM People)
    SELECT id, name
    FROM MyPeople
    WHERE row = 1

    -- Better
    SELECT DISTINCT id, name
    FROM People
    ```

Comment: Not work for me, better https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573451

Comment: @Kiquenet It worked just fine for me (Azure SQL Database). Maybe you are on an older version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 21):

Try more elegant way (but, it's solution works only in MS SQL 2008 or higher) -

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      [object_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
    , o.type_desc
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.usp_test1', 'OBJECT') d
JOIN sys.objects o ON d.referenced_id = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] IN ('U', 'V')
```

Comment: Use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573451

Answer (score 16):

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS (
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P')
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005** it it recommended to use the more focused system catalog views - like `sys.tables` and `sys.procedures` instead of the "general purpose" `sys.objects` (and `sysobjects` is deprecated anyway)

Comment: @marc_s, agreed!  I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23698250/1366033) that uses the updated tables.

Comment: What is the reason of using `ROW_NUMBER()` here? Isn't it easier to do just `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Looks like other dependent objects are also included here.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the sql code for this

### To get list of tables used in a stored procedure

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS (
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P')
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

.

### *Reverse* - To find Stored Procedure Related to Table in Database – Search in All Stored Procedure

There two ways to this

```
----Option 1
SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'

----Option 2
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype
FROM syscomments c
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
```

*PS: `sp_help` and `sp_depends` does not always return accurate results.*

Reference:

1. [Sql Server Central - Get list of tables used in a stored procedure](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic401606-444-2.aspx#bm1418137)
2. [SqlAuthority - Find Stored Procedure Related to Table in Database – Search in All Stored Procedure](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/10/sql-server-find-stored-procedure-related-to-table-in-database-search-in-all-stored-procedure/)

Comment: Use sys.sql_expression_dependencies - view https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573451

Answer (score 7):

[KyleMit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698250/104169) is using a table that will be deprecated soon as well. It is recommended to use sys.sql_experssion_dependencies instead of sys.sql_dependencies, e.g.,

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name AS proc_name, t.name AS table_name
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
INNER JOIN sys.procedures p ON p.object_id = d.referencing_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables t     ON t.object_id = d.referenced_id
ORDER BY proc_name, table_name
```

This should work with SQL Server 2008+.

I did not have a high enough reputation to comment directly on the referenced answer.

Comment: Above KyleMit's answer is not giving proper results, but this answer query is giving correct results.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there is no complete answer for OP question. Most of the answers above don't have either schema name or include other objects (e.g. functions) used in stored procedures.

**Full list of tables/views used in stored procedures with schema name and object id**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        procObj.[object_id]     AS [ProcObjectId],
        procSchema.[name]       AS [ProcSchema],
        procObj.[Name]          AS [ProcName], 
        tableObj.[object_id]    AS [TableObjectId],
        tableSchema.[name]      AS [TableSchema],
        tableObj.[Name]         AS [TableName]
FROM sys.sql_dependencies AS dep
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS procObj
ON procObj.[object_id] = dep.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS procSchema 
ON procSchema.[schema_id] = procObj.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS tableObj
ON tableObj.[object_id] = dep.[referenced_major_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS tableSchema 
ON tableSchema.[schema_id] = tableObj.[schema_id]
WHERE   procObj.[type] = 'P' 
    -- using this filter we can control dependent object types
    -- e.g. tableObj.[type] IN ('U') - returns tables only
    AND tableObj.[type] IN ('V', 'U')
```

Note that there is a filter on dependent object types which can be changed (depends on what you want in output results). Full list of type abbreviations is 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
NAME 
FROM SYSOBJECTS 
WHERE ID IN (   SELECT SD.DEPID 
                FROM SYSOBJECTS SO, 
                SYSDEPENDS SD
                WHERE SO.NAME = 'SP_NAME' 
                AND SD.ID = SO.ID
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

But please note that the `sysdepends` will not give the table names if they are used in **dynamic sql**. What I suggest is to search reversely 
ie: create a loop search the tables in the `syscomments`. The below stored procedure may help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_getObjects
(
    @ObjName VARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Idkeyst INTEGER
    DECLARE @Idkeyed INTEGER
    DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @Objects VARCHAR(MAX)
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where NAME = @ObjName AND type in ('P', 'FN','TR'))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO Text Available for the Parameter'
        RETURN(0)
    END
    CREATE TABLE #ProcStr
    (
        Idkey       INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        ScriptStr   VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    CREATE TABLE #Depends
    (
        Idkey           INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Depends         VARCHAR(255)
    )
    CREATE TABLE #Objects
    (
        Idkey           INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        ObjectName      VARCHAR(255)
    )
    INSERT INTO #ProcStr
    (ScriptStr)
    EXEC sp_helptext @ObjName
    DELETE #ProcStr WHERE LTRIM(ScriptStr) LIKE '--%'
    DELETE #ProcStr WHERE LTRIM(REPLACE(ScriptStr,CHAR(9),'')) LIKE '--%'

    SET @Idkeyst = 0
    SET @Idkeyed = 0
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Idkeyst = MIN(idKey) FROM #ProcStr WHERE ScriptStr like '%/*%' and Idkey > @Idkeyst
        IF @Idkeyst IS NULL
            BREAK
        SELECT @Idkeyed = MIN(idKey) FROM #ProcStr WHERE ScriptStr like '%*/%' and Idkey >= @Idkeyst
        DELETE #ProcStr WHERE Idkey >= @Idkeyst and Idkey <=@Idkeyed
    END
    DELETE #ProcStr WHERE ISNULL(LTRIM(REPLACE(ScriptStr,CHAR(9),'')),'')=''    
    INSERT INTO #Depends
    (Depends)
    SELECT DISTINCT t.name 
    FROM sys.sql_dependencies d 
    INNER JOIN sys.procedures p ON p.object_id = d.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables     t ON t.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
    where p.name = @ObjName

    INSERT INTO #Objects
    SELECT name from sys.objects o WHERE Type = 'U' AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM #Depends WHERE Depends = o.name)

    SET @Objects = ''
    SELECT @Objects = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Objects,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE @Objects+', ' END+ Depends
    FROM #Depends

    UPDATE #ProcStr
    SET ScriptStr = LTRIM(RTRIM(ScriptStr))
    UPDATE #ProcStr
    SET ScriptStr = REPLACE(ScriptStr,CHAR(9),'')
    UPDATE #ProcStr
    SET ScriptStr = REPLACE(ScriptStr,CHAR(13),'')
    UPDATE #ProcStr
    SET ScriptStr = REPLACE(ScriptStr,CHAR(10),'')
    SET @tblName = ''
    SET @Idkeyst = 0
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Idkeyst = MIN(idKey) FROM #Objects WHERE Idkey > @Idkeyst
        IF @Idkeyst IS NULL
            BREAK
        SELECT @tblName = ObjectName FROM #Objects WHERE Idkey = @Idkeyst
        IF Exists (SELECT 1 FROM #ProcStr WHERE (ScriptStr LIKE '% '+@tblName+' %' 
                        OR ScriptStr LIKE '%.'+@tblName+' %' OR ScriptStr LIKE @tblName+' %' OR ScriptStr LIKE @tblName
                        --OR ScriptStr LIKE '%'+@tblName 
                        OR ScriptStr LIKE '% '+@tblName+'''%' OR ScriptStr LIKE @tblName+'''%'))
        BEGIN
            SET @Objects = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Objects,'')<>'' THEN @Objects+', '+@tblName ELSE @tblName END
        END
    END

    IF ISNULL(@Objects,'') = ''
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO Tables are reffered in the stored procedures'
        RETURN(0)
    END
    PRINT @Objects
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: Don't understand why this was down voted? Is it not mandatory to give a comment while you are down voting a post? For my understanding, we could not rely on sysdepends.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to find list of tables used in a procedure

```
;WITH procs
AS
(
SELECT o1.name AS proc_name,
o2.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o1.name,o2.name ORDER BY o1.name,o2.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d
INNER JOIN sysobjects o1
ON o1.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects o2
ON o2.id=d.depid
WHERE o1.xtype = 'P'
--AND o2.name = 'tabname1' OR o2.name = 'tblname2'
)
SELECT proc_name, table_name
FROM procs
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY proc_name, table_name
```

Also, this query returns all the table names of all dependent tables in a Stored procedure.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id, o.name as 'Procedure_Name' , oo.name as 'Table_Name'
FROM sysdepends d, sysobjects o, sysobjects oo
WHERE o.id=d.id 
and oo.id=d.depid and depnumber=1
ORDER BY o.name,oo.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This code recursively looks at every Stored Procedure in your Stored Procedure and gives you the full list of all tables used.

```
    declare @sp_name varchar(100)
    declare @curSpName varchar(100)
    declare @curObjName varchar(255)
    declare @curXType varchar(1)
    ​
    create table #tmpTables
    (
    proc_name varchar(255),
    table_name varchar(255)
    )
    ​
    set @sp_name = 'STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME'
    ​
    ;WITH stored_procedures AS (
    SELECT 
    o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name, oo.type AS xType,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name, oo.Type ORDER BY o.name,oo.name, oo.Type) AS row
    FROM sysdepends d 
    INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
    INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
    WHERE o.xtype = 'P'
    --and oo.type = 'U' --Tables
    and o.name = @sp_name)
    SELECT proc_name, table_name, xType, 'N' Processed into ##tmpSP
    FROM stored_procedures 
    WHERE row = 1
    --ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
    ​
    ​
    While (Select count(*) from ##tmpSP where Processed = 'N')  0
    Begin
    ​
        Select top  1 @curSpName = proc_name, @curObjName = table_name, @curXType = xType
        from ##tmpSP
        where Processed = 'N'
    ​
    ​
        if @curXType = 'U'
        Begin
    ​
            insert into #tmpTables
            values (@curSpName, @curObjName)
    ​
        End
    ​
        if @curXType = 'P'
        Begin
    ​
            ;WITH stored_procedures AS (
            SELECT 
            o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name, oo.type AS xType,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name, oo.Type ORDER BY o.name,oo.name, oo.Type) AS row
            FROM sysdepends d 
            INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
            INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
            WHERE o.xtype = 'P'
            and oo.type = 'U' --Tables
            and o.name = @curObjName)
            insert into #tmpTables
            SELECT @curSpName, table_name 
            FROM stored_procedures 
            WHERE row = 1
            ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
    ​
            ;WITH stored_procedures AS (
            SELECT 
            o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name, oo.type AS xType,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name, oo.Type ORDER BY o.name,oo.name, oo.Type) AS row
            FROM sysdepends d 
            INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
            INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
            WHERE o.xtype = 'P'
            and oo.type = 'P' --SP's
            and o.name = @curObjName)
            insert into ##tmpSP
            SELECT proc_name, table_name, xType, 'N'  
            FROM stored_procedures 
            WHERE row = 1
            and proc_name not in 
            (
                Select proc_name
                from ##tmpSP
            )
            ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
    ​
        End
    ​
        if @curXType = 'v'
        Begin
    ​
            ;WITH stored_procedures AS (
            SELECT 
            o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name, oo.type AS xType,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name, oo.Type ORDER BY o.name,oo.name, oo.Type) AS row
            FROM sysdepends d 
            INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
            INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
            WHERE o.xtype = 'v'
            and oo.type = 'U' --Tables
            and o.name = @curObjName)
            insert into #tmpTables
            SELECT proc_name, table_name 
            FROM stored_procedures 
            WHERE row = 1
            ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
    ​
        End
    ​
        update ##tmpSP
        set Processed = 'Y'
        where table_name = @curObjName
    ​
    ​
    End
    ​
    ​
    Select distinct table_name
    from #tmpTables
    ​
    drop table #tmpTables
    drop table ##tmpSP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%Tablename%'
```