# List of tables used in all stored procedures with SP's schema name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How do we get list of tables used in all stored procedures with stored procedure's schema name? I have seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229493/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-tables-in-the-stored-procedure). But it is not listing the stored procedure’s schema name. Does anybody know how to  retrieve the schema name of stored procedure too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

This will return all stored procedure in the current database and also the schema associated with it.

If you want to get the tables and related stored procedure try something like this:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_NAME, s.ROUTINE_NAME,s.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES s 
ON s.ROUTINE_NAME IN 
(
        SELECT referencing_entity_name 
        FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT')
)
AND s.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Stay away from the sysobject etc views