# Could we get list of tables used inside one stored procedures with dml or ddl operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could we get list of tables used inside one stored procedures with dml or ddl operations
ex:
table name -select ,insert, update, delete

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the list of tables in the stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229493/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-tables-in-the-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;WITH stored_procedures AS (
      SELECT 
      o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
      FROM sysdepends d 
      INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
      INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
      WHERE o.xtype = 'P')
      SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
      WHERE row = 1
      ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this code:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    [object_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
   , o.type_desc
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.sp_name', 'OBJECT') d
    JOIN sys.objects o ON d.referenced_id = o.[object_id]
    WHERE o.[type] IN ('U', 'V')
```