# List tables used in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is More than 1000 stored procedures in my database. I have some list of stored procedures For a particular module. I am in a need to find the list of tables used in a particular stored procedure.To do it i have to open all the stored procedures and manually take the list of tables used. I need some Trans SQL query to do this job.

Comment: please search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229493/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-tables-in-the-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally modified the code..

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS
(
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name)AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P'
)
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1 and proc_name in('sp1','sp2','sp3')
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```