# script to identify all the tables that are not been used in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Can I have a script to identify all the tables that are not been used in stored procedure.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT name AS Tables_Not_Used_By_SP
FROM   sys.tables
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT t.name AS table_name
FROM   sys.sql_dependencies d
       INNER JOIN sys.procedures p
               ON p.object_id = d.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.tables t
               ON t.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
```

Referred this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229493/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-tables-in-the-stored-procedure/23698250#23698250)** to find the dependent tables

Answer (score 1):

I am combining the 2 queries into one

1) To get all the tables from the database
2) NOT IN all dependency tables

```
   SELECT 
        * 
   FROM 
        sys.tables 
   WHERE 
       object_id NOT IN (
             SELECT d.referenced_major_id 
             FROM sys.sql_dependencies d 
                  INNER JOIN sys.procedures p 
                     ON p.object_id = d.object_id
                        )
   ORDER BY name
```