# SQL server get a list of tables used in stored procedure Including Linked tables(tables from difrente databases)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

as the title says I have a query I can get all the tables except the linked ones, this is my code for getting all the tables, im working with sql 2008.

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS
(
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name)AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P'
)
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1 and proc_name = 'SPNamehere'
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229493/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-tables-in-the-stored-procedure

Comment: [sysdepends is a view created for backwards compatibility to SQL Server 2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdepends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - if you don't need this you should use [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - which includes cross-database and cross-server entities

Comment: All of them will either return me one table or like mine will give me all the tables that are present in the database but not the linked ones from another database, im working with 2 databases in the same server